# Ordered sum of posets

Tags: set-theory, posets

Let $I$ be a poset and for any $i$ let $P_i$ be a poset. Let $P$ be the sum over $I$ of the sets $P_i$, and let $<_P$ be the relation defined on $P$ by $q<_Pr$ iff $q$ and $r$ are members of the same $P_i$ and $q<_ir$ or $q$ is member of $P_j$ $r$ is member of $P_k$ and $j<_ik$. Maybe that formally, I should have taken $Q_i$ as the cartesian product of the singleton of $i$ with $P_i$, and $Q$ as the union of the $Q_i$'s, and compared couples as $(i,q)$ and $(j,r)$. Anyway, it is clear that $P$, equipped with our relation is a poset, that is the poset sum over $I$ of the posets $P_i$. Particularly, in the case that $I$ and $P_i$ all are totally ordered sets , $P$ is a totally ordered set. And, in this particular case, a theorem of Schoenflies asserts that "every (totally) ordered set is the union of scattered sets over a densely ordered indexing set";

> Question: does there exist a similar decomposition theorem in the general case of posets ?

Gérard Lang

Comment: @Gérard LANG, I've taken the liberty to edit your text into LaTeX and fixed a few spelling mistakes.  Please re-edit if I've made the wrong choices in some places.

Comment: Sorry, I did something similar as jc, in parallel. I then rolled back to jc's version as it was better than mine. 

Comment: That theorem of Schoenflies is quite interesting. Where can one find it? Could you perhaps spell out when subsets are scattered?

Comment: If $\lt_i$ means the order of $P_i$, then in the case where q and $r$ come from different posets, you want to say $$j\lt_I k$ rather than $j\lt_i k$. Your order is also often denoted $\Sigma_{i\in I}P_i$, and one way to picture it is that you start with $I$, and replace each node $i\in I$ with a copy of $P_i$. 

Comment: I rewrote my question because I thought it would not be readable. The  theorem is given inside "Set Theory by  Kuratowski and Mostowski(with an introduction to Descriptive set theory)" theorem 5 ,page 209. A linearly ordered set which contains no infinite densely ordered subset is said to be scattered; a set is densely ordered if for any two elements there exists another element strictly between them.
Gérard lang

Comment: @Chris: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattered_order for two equivalent definitions. The theorem is then actually easy to prove: for $x\le y$, let $x\sim y$ iff the interval $[x,y]$ is scattered. This gives you an equivalence relation, and it is not hard to see that each equivalence class is a convex scattered subset, and $P/{\sim}$ is densely ordered.

Comment: I think that at least the notion of scattered has to be relaxed. Let $X$ be any finite set of cardinality at least two, take $I=\{0<1\}$, and let $P_0=P_1$ be the powerset of $X$. Then any totally ordered subset of $P=\sum_{i in I} P_i$ is scattered, but $P$ is not a sum over any densely ordered poset.

Comment: It's to be expected that something has to be relaxed somewhere, but in this particular example, $P$ is finite, hence it would natural to declare it scattered itself?

Comment: 1-The initial source given by Kuratowski and Mostowski is:
A. Schoenflies; "Entwickelung der Mengenlehre und ihren Anwendungen" (Development of the theory of sets and its applications) p. 184(Leipzig-Berlin) 1913.
2-Yes, the proof for totaly orderd sets goes like written by Emil Jerabek
Gérard Lang

Comment: Garrett Birkhoff defined a form of arithmetic on posets, which I believe included exponentiation.  Recent researchers on this include Ralph McKenzie and Jonathan Farley.  I suspect this is either related directly to your question, or is one or at most two citation links away from a paper that addresses your question.  (I do not recall if the arithmetic was over finite or over arbitrary posets.)  Gerhard "Two Plus Two Equals Twotwo" Paseman, 2011.06.29

Comment: In the theorem of Schoenflies you mention, should it be that every ordered set is the <b>sum</b> of scattered sets over a densely ordered index set, rather than a <b>union</b>?

Comment: Kuratowski and Mostowski (following Schoenflies?) write "union", but it is pretty clear from the proof that this is a disjoint union, so isomorphic to a sum of order types.
Gérard Lang

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first restricting to, say, suborders $P$ of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$(with the product ordering where $(x_1,y_1)\leq(x_2,y_2)$ iff $x_1\leq x_2$ and $y_1\leq y_2$). See if you can find a satisfactory decomposition there, focusing on simple counterexamples to a straight generalization of Schoenflies' Theorem.

For example, let 
$$P=(\{0\}\times[0,1])\cup\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty(\{2^{-n} \}\times\{m\cdot 2^{-n}:m=1,\ldots,2^n\}).$$ Suppose you had a decomposition of $P$ into an ordered sum 
where the index has some property D reminiscent of denseness 
and each summand has property S reminiscent of scatteredness. 
If the linear order $[0,1]$ lacks property S, then you must decompose $P$ into singletons. 
Hence, either $[0,1]$ has property S or $P$ has property D.
(Neither of these options looks appealing to me.)